# Firestore "Stream Removed" Error After 3 Minutes Doing Nothing

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working on .NET Windows Form App which uses Google Cloud Firestore as Database. I've created functions (using Google.Cloud.Firestore NuGet Package functions) to read/write database documents. Everything working greatly but if app doesn't use any of this read/write functions more than 2-3 minutes, i'm getting this error: `Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Stream removed"` But if uses read/write functions every 1-2 minutes, i do not get this error in short period. I can create a thread function to keep my database connection active but it causes unnecessary reads or writes. How can i solve it?

**To Reproduce Error**

```
string Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"AdminSDKName.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Path);
FirestoreDb DataBase = FirestoreDb.Create("DatabaseID");
Query QRef = DataBase.Collection("CollectionID").Document("DocID").Collection("CollectionID").WhereEqualTo("isTrue", false);
QuerySnapshot snap = await QRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
Console.WriteLine(snap.Count.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for 5 minutes..");
Task.Delay(300000).Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Waited for 5 minutes");
snap = await QRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
Console.WriteLine(snap.Count.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Done without any error.");
```

I get error after "Waited for 5 minutes" line.

**Update**

If i connect my computer network to mobile phone network i do not get any error.

Comment: This [Github issue link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22462) explains that the issue was with GRPC server enabled with default development certificate, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ZeenathSN I'm not using API.NET and he mentioned "requires SSL". Is there a way that i can change FirestoreDB client settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're seeing a part of Firestore's connection management here. If that's indeed what we're seeing, the connection should be reestablished when needed and there's nothing you can change about this through the API.

Comment: I changed my network and didn't get an error. It's something about my network. Something closes my TCP connection but i do not know what it is.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. It might be anything in between the client and server that does that, but I'd expect the Firestore SDK to handle recovery in many such cases. Is there any functional problem besides the error that's being logged?

Comment: No it's just "Stream Removed" error.  Firewall or another defenders could cause that problem?

Comment: Yes, that could be. But does the Firestore SDK work after you see that message?

Comment: How can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to find out what is closing the stream prematurely. The configuration of Grpc.Core to send a keepalive packet once a minute can be found in the [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-dotnet/blob/main/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ClientBuilderBase.cs#L26).

I suggest you try the code on a few different networks if you can, keeping everything else the same, to see if you can identify what is closing the connection.

Comment: I tried it with different network(mobile network) and it worked but i don't know how can identify what is closing connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [User guide](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/userguide).

If this does not resolve, update your question with minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I've updated question. You can reproduce the error.